# При объединении файлов SVG с помощью svgutils слетает кириллица

Tags: svg, кодировка, utf-8, кириллица

У меня есть 2 SVG файла. В одном из них (петля мебиуса) текст написан кириллицей. Когда объединяю его с другим SVG (со штрих кодом) и открываю получившийся SVG, то текст кириллицей превращается в абракадабру (слетает кодировка?).

```
import svgutils.transform as sg
import sys
import re


MEBIUS = sg.fromfile('Mebius.svg')

CODE_EAN13 = sg.fromfile('EAN13.svg')

root = logo.getroot()

root.moveto(60, 375, scale_x=2)

background.append([root])

background.save('output.svg')
```

output.svg в итоге выглядит так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD8ST.png

Вот как выглядит mebius в оригинале: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKgM2.png

UPD: Пробовала поставить #coding=utf-8.Не помогло. Сделала print('2.svg', 'r'), оказалось:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='2.svg' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>
```

Стала смотреть на конфигурацию файлов SVG. Исходный mebius:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Финальный файл output SVG:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII' standalone='yes'?>
```

Также в финальном файле текст "фффф" отображается как `&#1057;&#8222;&#1057;&#8222;&#1057;&#8222;&#1057;&#8222;`

Нагуглила, что это html-entities. Если его перевести в СР1251, затем в UTF - 8, то получим исходные "фффф"

Comment: А пробовали поставить вначале #coding=utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

Ура! Решила!

##### Шаг 1. Задаём для output.svg формат ср1251

```
background.save('output.svg', encoding='cp1251')
```

Если после первого шага зайти в код файла output, то увидим, что переменная, отвечающая за кириллицу, отображается корректно:
`>ТЕКСТ ЗДЕСЬ</text>`
Но при этом в первой строке с кодировкой стоит оторый не считывается ни браузером, ни графическим редактором. `encoding='cp1251' standalone='yes'?>`,

Если задавать кодировку utf-8, то наш SVG откроется и в браузере, и в иллюстраторе (Adobe Illustrator), но в тексте будет появляться абракадабра `>СѓРєРµСѓРєРїСѓ</text>`

##### Шаг 2. Ипортируем кодаки

```
import codecs
```

##### Шаг 3. Открываем только что созданный SVG и читаем его в кодировке utf-8

При этом с помощью replace меняем 'cp1251' на 'utf-8'. Получается, что файле SVG мы убираем название переменной encoding, но оставляем правильное отображение текста

```
f = codecs.open('output.svg', 'r', 'utf-8')
u = f.read()
u = u.replace('cp1251','utf-8')

out = codecs.open('output.svg', 'w', 'utf-8')
out.write(u)
print(u)
```

##### Готово!)

[image: Вот что вышло)]

##### Итоговый код:

```
import svgutils.transform as sg
import sys
import re
import codecs


background = sg.fromfile('Mebius.svg')
logo = sg.fromfile('Baracode.svg')
root = logo.getroot()

# Top Left
root.moveto(60, 375, scale_x=2)

background.append([root])

background.save('output.svg', encoding='cp1251')

f = codecs.open('output.svg', 'r', 'utf-8')
u = f.read()
u = u.replace('cp1251','utf-8')

out = codecs.open('output.svg', 'w', 'utf-8')
out.write(u)
print(u)
```

Comment: Почему сразу не задать utf в бакграунде?